# Magento 2: How to call logo in phtml file

Tags: magento2

I was trying to call logo in custom phtml file with following code.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Theme\Block\Html")->setTemplate("Magento_Theme::html/header/logo.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 6):

We can call logo with following code..

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo")->setTemplate("Magento_Theme::html/header/logo.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```